# Is there a way to deploy a Maven project with "jar" packaging into Tomcat7?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

My project generates a Jar as the output package and uses an external War file, available on our Artifactory, as the Web Application to be deployed on Tomcat (currently using version 7). This War file contains all libs and modules required for the application to run.

I have already packaged and ran those projects outside eclipse on a "vanilla" Tomcat installation. In this scenario, the Jar my project generates is loaded on the context.xml file this way:

```
<Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader" virtualClasspath="/home/igor/workspace/myapp/myapp-2.4.3.jar"/>
```

Is there a way I can deploy this project on Tomcat using Eclipse and still be able to debug it? Can I use the Jar generated for this purpose or do I have to deploy the workspace project?
As for the War file, do (or can) I have to add it as an dependency?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

We actually provide an Web Framework, which is packaged as a war. Other applications that use that framework are exported as jars and loaded into the framework through the context file as cited above.

Comment: Your question is kind of confusing; why are you loading your application as a jar? Why not build a war directly? Or why not include your jar as a dependency in your war project?

Comment: We actually provide an Web Framework, which is packaged as a war. Other applications that use that framework are exported as jars and loaded into the framework through the context file as cited above. Sorry for being confusing. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is confusing probably because of your custom plugin/classloader and deployment which is sort of orthogonal to debugging.

What I recommend is you keep whatever system you have to build/package/deploy and use JVM remote debugging. That is do not use the Eclipse WTP since you seem to have custom steps for deployment but rather build your code deploy & run a separate Tomcat instance and then run the [remote debugger in Eclipse](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing#Q2).

You will get some hotcode swapping with this method but not as much as something like JRebel.. (which you could use also) it will certainly be better than constantly redeploying.

Comment: Thanks, Adam. It was actually one of our initial options, but we were resistant to it. As of now, we're using Eclipse WTP normally, but since it requires some effort to configure build paths for projects and Tomcat, I'm converting our Projects to Maven Projects. I mean, we could keep deploying to our localhosts the same way as before and use Maven just for dependencies and publishing stuff in Artifactory. Anyways, I'll put some more thinking into it. Thanks, again.

Comment: Well if you do decide to stick with WTP and want to use Maven you will need to use the m2e-wtp plugin which most of the time works but only works for WAR projects. The other option is you could make your own hotdeploy where a plugin JAR is uploaded to your running Tomcat. Some systems like Jenkins (I think) use this method.